# I think I pressed something by accident, and now my regular movements are jittery.

Tags: edit-mode

Normally when I press the "g" key everything is smooth. But suddenly as I was working on my model. Everything is moving very jittery and I cant control anything that is happening. The vertices would jump around the point but wont land at the specific area I want. Is there a way I could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You might have accidently turned on snapping tool. Check if the magnet button on the botton of 3D View is not turned on. Otherwise, please provide .blend file for better feedback.